# How to vertically center a Bootstrap container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I vertically center this Bootstrap container div? I want it so I view the page it centers vertically on the page with black above and below my div.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/yunr225g/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
      <button type="submit">Stay</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
      <button type="submit">Leave</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 10px;
  background:black;
}
button {
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin:60px auto;
  background:black;
  border:2px solid #ffca00;
  padding:30px;
  width:250px;
  color:#ffca00;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll have to set all the parent elements of the container to `height:100%`, or use `height:100vh` directly. Then, use the `position` + `transform` tricks to center it vertically.

This works good on larger screens, you might need to tweak it via media queries + break points for smaller screens.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ubyLvdps/)**

Or, try this CSS table approach, it seems to be working good, and doesn't affect Bootstrap grid. Note, added two extra divs as wrappers.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}
.container1 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuygrvss/)**